# Choosing a set of random values from one column where another column matches a certain criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm producing an Excel report where I need to input a randomised selection from a data column, but to omit the human element of selection (for audit purposes).

The column names are "Date", "Staff Name" and "Cad Number".

The "Cad number" column is specific to the "staff member" on a particular date.

Is it possible to enter a command for the report to select 5 random "cad numbers" per "staff member"?

Comment: Hi-I've tried to use the rand formula but can only use it specific to one column i.e. the "cad number" column to give 5 random numbers. I can't/or don't have the relevant knowledge to actually link the name column to the cad number column to carry out this function. Attempted a macro but without the formula or array to carry out the command i cant get it going either

Comment: Please [edit](//superuser.com/posts/1348934/edit) your answer, and add the information from your comment, While you're at it please add a screenshot of some sample data and/or a formatted table of the data (use `Ctrl`+`K` or click the { } icon).

Comment: For start.. do `=RANDBETWEEN(1,5)` and share your results.. || Some info are missing from your question. Like is the staff number repeated? + is the card number are allowed to be repeated? + does each staff will only have 1 card or multiple cards? || A sample data would help to clarify your Q

Comment: OK-I will try add some test data but for starters I have a set number of staff names i.e. 50 names with each having approx 300 cad numbers against their name which for audit purposes I would like excel to randomise down to 5 random cad numbers per staff name. the '=randbetween(1,5)' is good if I only want one specific staff name but I want excel to do this for the complete staff name column. Again hopefully I am making sense and thank you for the help so far.

Comment: staff name cad number
Bill 1607838
Bill 1677385
Bill 1607385
Phil 1607877
Phil 1607789
Phil 1699880
Belle 1688989
Belle 1678793
Belle 1676652
George 1679898
George 1655886
George 1677955

Comment: Please [edit](//superuser.com/posts/1348934/edit) your question, and add the information from your comments. (My previous comment should also have said "question", not "answer" ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

Do 2 list.. 1st to generate the random sequence, 2nd to call the randomized sequence cad number.

list A ( and put it in column A, start at A2 ), the 300 cad list. should occupy `A2:A301`
then in `B2` put `=RAND()` , then drag downwards till end of list.
in `C2` put `=RANK(B2,B:B,0)` , then drag downwards till end of list.

list B ( and put it in column E, start at `E2` ), a running number from 1 to 250.
then in `F2` onwards, the staff namex5.. should occupy `F2:F251` Eg Bill1,Bill2,Bill3,Bill4,Bill5,Phil1,Phil2,Phil3,Phil4,Phil5,Belle1,Belle2.... 
Then in `G2`, put `=index(A:A,match(E2;C:C,0))`, then drag downwards till end of list.

I think that's it. Have a try.